# what does it mean by "used to" in the context below?

Tags: past-participles

CONTEXT:

> We love life, not because we are "used to living" but because we are "used to loving".

As far as I know it is used to state the activity that a person does not do now but used to do in past. But in this what does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

This is easy to understand when explained simply:

to be used to + verb with ing (gerund: living):

We are **used to living** = We are **accustomed to living**

**VERSUS**

Subject + used to + verb without ing (no gerund):**

We **used to live** in that city. = /used to/ describes a situation that is no longer true.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom *SUBJ used to VERB*, where the verb is *use*, does mean "SUBJ made a practise of VERB in the past"; but *BE used to VERBing* is a different idiom. Here *used* is an adjective derived from the passive participle of *use*, with the sense *inured, accustomed*, so the idiom means "BE accustomed to the fact or action of VERBING". "We are used to living" and "We are used to loving" means that we have a great deal of experience of those activities.